# requestFocus() focuses a TextView, but does not highlight it

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, focus, highlight

I have a Datalogic Memor K – a mobile computer which runs Android 9 and has a hardware keyboard.

In my application, I can move the focus/highlight between controls, including TextView controls with isFocusableInTouchMode = true, manually using the hardware arrow keys (see below).

But when I do it programmatically, requestFocus() returns true, but the TextView does not highlight, although it seems to get the focus, because the next move with the arrow keys starts from it.

[image: Screenshot]

I create a project from the **Empty activity** template.
For better visibility, I add the following to the res/value/themes.xml file:

```xml
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/purple_700</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

To keep my post shorter, I don't use a layout file and do everything in the code of the main activity:

```kotlin
@file:SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
package lv.trialto.myapplication

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val numbers = arrayOf("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine")
        var nextNumberIndex = 0

        val rootLinearLayout = LinearLayout(this).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT)
            orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
        }

        val textViewList = mutableListOf<TextView>()

        for (y in 1..3) {
            val horizontalLinearLayout = LinearLayout(this).apply {
                layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
                orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL
            }

            rootLinearLayout.addView(horizontalLinearLayout)

            for (x in 1..3) {
                val cell = TextView(this).apply {
                    width = (100 * context.resources.displayMetrics.density + 0.5).toInt()
                    isFocusableInTouchMode = true
                    text = numbers[nextNumberIndex++]
                }

                textViewList.add(cell)
                horizontalLinearLayout.addView(cell)
            }
        }

        rootLinearLayout.addView(Button(this).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
            text = "Focus random cell"
            setOnClickListener {
                val randomTextView = textViewList[textViewList.indices.random()]
                val saveText = randomTextView.text
                randomTextView.text = "HERE!"
                val result = randomTextView.requestFocus()
                Toast.makeText(context, "result = $result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    delay(1000)
                    randomTextView.text = saveText
                }
            }
        })

        setContentView(rootLinearLayout)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, what is the correct name of this focus/highlight/cursor?

Comment: The highlight that you're seeing is a fallback used when a `View` doesn't have a background or foreground that handles `state_focused`. That fallback only shows when certain criteria are met, and one of those is that the `View` is _not_ in touch mode. In the given example, touch clicking the button puts everything in touch mode, so when the random `TextView` gains focus, the fallback indicator is _not_ displayed. If you use the keyboard to click the button – e.g, with the space or enter key – then it works as you were expecting, because it's not in touch mode when the focus shifts.

Comment: The safest thing to do is to provide a background or foreground for the `TextView`s that handles the focused state. I modified your example a bit to use one of the standard platform drawables that's known to handle it, just for demonstration: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ei4l3wibUGgKlJzAAK32q0SQwQTW89C8/view?usp=share_link.

Comment: Thank you, @MikeM. It worked.

I explored the inheritence path of my application theme (`Theme.MyApplication` → `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar` → `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar` → `Base.Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`) and found out that the default value of `listChoiceBackgroundIndicator` is `@drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark`. I googled that name and found [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/HEAD/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark.xml). Now I know that the drawable must...

Comment: Now I know that drawable must have the `/selector/item[@android:state_focused="true"]` part to work as I expect. I was able to create one like that. Now I'm wondering: how does the resource referenced by `<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abc_list_focused_holo" />` use the `colorControlHighlight` setting of my current theme? What is the right way to find `@drawable/abc_list_focused_holo` (and also `@drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark`) instead of googling?

Comment: Well, no, the attribute I used is `android.R.attr.listChoiceBackgroundIndicator`, which is the platform one, and with a modern theme it resolves to [`list_choice_background_material`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/drawable/list_choice_background_material.xml), which is colored with [`list_highlight_material`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/color/list_highlight_material.xml), which is where the platform's `colorControlHightlight` is specified. The `MaterialComponents` theme is setting the plaform…

Comment: …`colorControlHightlight` to its library `colorControlHightlight` value, which is what you're setting in that theme `<item>`. The `listChoiceBackgroundIndicator` you're looking at is the library attribute and it resolves to the platform attribute starting with API level 21: https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/appcompat/appcompat/src/main/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml#L82. Only the very base themes set the old holo values, which are only used on versions <21: https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/appcompat/appcompat/src/main/res/values/themes_base.xml#L235

Comment: @MikeM., is there a documentation that explains how Android apps work and, in particular, what platform attributes and themes are?

Comment: There's [the developer pages](https://developer.android.com) in general, and then [this section on Styles and Themes](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/themes), but I don't really know what's covered there. The complete list of platform attributes is on [this page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr), but it's just one big alphabetical list. The docs for each `View` will cover the ones it supports; e.g., [`TextView`'s XML attributes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#xml-attributes).