# foreground ignored if textAlignment=viewEnd and singleLine=true in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, textview, highlight

I create a new project from "Empty activity" template in the latest Android Studio and replace the contents of activity_main.xml with the code below.

Why isn't the bottom TextView blue?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="#800000FF"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Hello,"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="#800000FF"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="world!"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the result:

[image: Screenshot]

Why isn't the bottom TextView blue?
Is it an Android bug?

Comment: It's starting to look like it's possibly a bug (maybe part of the reason that `singleLine` was deprecated?). The foreground isn't ignored; it's just not visibly drawn, for some reason. If you're looking for a fix, `android:maxLines="1"` seems to work, so far.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bug, but I haven't found it on the tracker yet. I've not pinned down exactly how yet, but the combination of those particular values causes the clip bounds to be set incorrectly, so nothing after the content is drawn; the foreground, scrollbars, overlay, etc. It's broken since at least Marshmallow, AFAICT, so you'll probably just want to use `maxLines` instead. That'd normally be my advice for anything that's deprecated and has an obvious replacement, but `singleLine` seems to be in some sort of quasi-deprecated state, as some (edge case) things are only possible with it, IIRC.

Comment: OK, so, I'm not sure if this is a bug or expected behavior, but it's ultimately due to a `View`'s foreground – which is the same size as its bounds – not being translated for the `View`'s scroll values. It'll happen in any one that uses the basic scrolling mechanism; e.g., `ScrollView`, `EditText`, etc. In this case, `singleLine` is causing the `TextView`'s internal `Layout`'s width to be set to a max of 1024*1024, and the `textAlignment` aligns the text within that very wide layout. The `TextView`'s `scrollX` is then adjusted to align that `Layout` and its text within the `TextView`'s bounds…

Comment: …but the foreground is still drawing at the original (0,0), which is ~1024*1023 out of bounds to the left. If yours is one of those cases that requires `singleLine`, you can restrict the layout's width by calling `textView.setHorizontallyScrolling(false)`, but that has to be done in code, after single-line is set. If that won't work for your setup, the foreground draw can be translated, but that would require a custom subclass. Of course, if `maxLines` will work for you, just stick with that.

Comment: Yes, it's deprecated, so now I use `android:lines="1"` instead. I think it should work the same as `maxLines` for a value of 1.

Comment: @MikeM. , you are good at exploring SDK source code. Could you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75389026) issue? I haven't found a way to debug the SDK source code yet.